# pymongo dreference not working

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have articles data and I have multiple tags for every article. So instead of storing and duplicating tags in the article, I created a separate collection for tags. After following [this gist](https://gist.github.com/sbastn/769687) on dreferencing, I tried

```
In [98]: tag = db.tags.find_one({'_id': ObjectId('5839644a41e729e3d36ed28f')})

In [99]: tag
Out[99]: {u'_id': ObjectId('5839644a41e729e3d36ed28f'), u'code': u'new'}

In [100]: article = db.articles.insert_one({'name': 'hello', 'heading': 'test 123', 'tag': DBRef(collection = "tags", id = '5839644a41e729e3d36ed28f')})

In [104]: article.inserted_id
Out[104]: ObjectId('58397eaea09e012ed4202c74')

In [105]: a = db.articles.find_one({'_id': ObjectId('58397eaea09e012ed4202c74')})

In [106]: a
Out[106]: 
{u'_id': ObjectId('58397eaea09e012ed4202c74'),
 u'heading': u'test 123',
 u'name': u'hello',
 u'tag': DBRef(u'tags', u'5839644a41e729e3d36ed28f')}

In [107]: a['tag']
Out[107]: DBRef(u'tags', u'5839644a41e729e3d36ed28f')

In [110]: tag = db.dereference(a['tag'])

In [112]: print tag
None
```

but I am not able to get the related tag. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confused about the difference between a string and an ObjectId in Python. This is a string:

```
'5839644a41e729e3d36ed28f'
```

This is an ObjectId:

```
ObjectId('5839644a41e729e3d36ed28f')
```

You have been constructing your DBRef with a string as the "id":

```
DBRef(collection="tags", id='5839644a41e729e3d36ed28f')
```

You need to construct your DBRef with an ObjectId as the "id" instead:

```
DBRef(collection="tags", id=ObjectId('5839644a41e729e3d36ed28f'))
```

Comment: I tried what you said. And when I do `tag = db.dreference(a['tag'])`, I get an error `TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'dreference' method on a 'Database' object it is failing because no such method exists.`. I guess it's because `dreference` method is actually not there. https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver

Comment: You're missing an "e": "dereference".

Comment: Yes. The gist is the only somewhat proper example for referencing and relied on that. Any good resource on `pymongo`? You seemed to have used it extensively.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't see your title (viz. Staff Engineer at MongoDB) until now. What am I saying "you seemed to have used it extensively" :)

Comment: No worries! The PyMongo documentation for DBRefs doesn't include an example: http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.dereference But for general PyMongo documentation, have you tried reading the tutorial?: http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html